# How to detect when row type does not match column type in sqlite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Using the `sqlite` module for Python, I have declared a column of data in my database to be of type `real`, but due to errors in the source data, some rows are of type `text`. This is fine, but when I pull the data, I want sqlite to throw an error if the row contains data of type `text` when the declared column type is `real`. How do I do this?

I have tried opening the database connection with

```
con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

however, calls to `fetchone()` do not throw any errors.

What would be the best way of detecting a discrepancy between the row datatype and the datatype declared for the column?

I have also considered cleaning up data before inserting into the database, but these anomalous `text` rows contain special codes that may have more relevance in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES`, you actually need to register a converter (or adapter for inserting) for the declared type, the only converters that are registered by default are for `DATE` and `DATETIME`.

If you want an error if a column declared as `real` is not numeric, it would be as simple as:

```
sqlite3.register_converter('real', float)
```